# Square root of a matrix (or a 2nd order tensor)

Tags: matrices, tensors

Suppose I have two symmetrical matrices $A$ and $C$.
Suppose they have the following relation
$$ A = C^{T} \cdot C = C^{2} $$
and I would like to solve this above equation for $C$ matrix.

Is it correct to write the solution in this form?
$$ C = A^{1/2} $$

If yes how to define square root of a matrix?

Comment: You should post this question to [matheamtics.stackexchange.com](http://mathematics.stackexchange.com).

Comment: You may want to look into trying to get the `CholeskyDecomposition` of `A` (assuming it exists), because that would give you a unique matrix `C`.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit The root is requested to be symmetric and Cholesky factors are not (by definition).

Comment: Ah, yes. I missed the part about `C` being symmetric.

Answer (score 6):

Nope, it's not correct. If `A` is positive semi-definite (as it is if it can be written as `A = Transpose[B].B`), you can do the following:

```
A = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {3, 3}];
A = Transpose[A].A;
{λ, U} = Eigensystem[A];
B = Transpose[U].(Sqrt[λ] U);
Max[Abs[B.B - A]]
Max[Abs[Transpose[B].B - A]]
```

> 1.55431*10^-15
>
> 1.55431*10^-15

Note that `B^2` squares each entry and is different from `MatrixPower[B,2]` (equal `B.B`).

Answer (score 3):

In general, one expects $2^n$ solutions to $C^2 = A$ if $A$ and $C$ are $n \times n$ matrices.  So this quickly gets out of hand as $n$ increases.  Here is code for find them:

```
nn = 2;
SeedRandom[4];
aij = RandomInteger[{-2, 2}, nn (nn + 1)/2];
aa = Statistics`Library`VectorToSymmetricMatrix[Drop[aij, nn], Take[aij, nn], nn];
MatrixForm[aa]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
vars = Array[x, nn (nn + 1)/2];
cc = Statistics`Library`VectorToSymmetricMatrix[Drop[vars, nn], Take[vars, nn], nn];
sols = cc /. Solve[cc.cc == aa, vars];
Map[MatrixForm, Simplify@sols]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Check:

```
MatrixForm /@ Simplify[#.# & /@ sols]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

You can get the "principal" square root using [`MatrixPower`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MatrixPower): Using Michael's example:

```
MatrixPower[{{0,1},{1,1}}, 1/2] //Simplify //TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  \frac{\left(-1+\sqrt{5}\right) \sqrt{1+\sqrt{5}}+i \sqrt{-1+\sqrt{5}}
>    \left(1+\sqrt{5}\right)}{2 \sqrt{10}} & \frac{-i
>    \sqrt{-1+\sqrt{5}}+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{5}}}{\sqrt{10}} \\
>  \frac{-i \sqrt{-1+\sqrt{5}}+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{5}}}{\sqrt{10}} & \frac{i
>    \left(-1+\sqrt{5}\right)^{3/2}+\left(1+\sqrt{5}\right)^{3/2}}{2 \sqrt{10}} \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$